# iPhone doesn't show location in certain apps

Tags: iphone, applications, ios, gps, geolocation

My iPhone 4 has several apps that I use location services on. But one set of 2 apps from the same developer will not show my location. They are enabled in Location Services, and show a grey arrow to show they have requested  location, but will not provide a location on their maps. I have a GPS Status app which reports at the correct location, as does google maps etc.

The apps have been removed and re-installed. reboots of the hardware have happened.
I'm wondering if there is a hardware fault, as the developer of the app reports no similar problems with iPhone users.

PS: iPhone 4 A1332 version 6.1.3 (10B329)

Comment: Which apps do show the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Very strange, by any chance do you have restrictions on under general settings? - would have left this as a comment but the arbitrary restriction due to "reputation"  means I have to leave it as an answer or not try to help at all. Well designed.